# Python2.7: How can I redirect texts with colors

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to add colors to texts in the following code in Python 2.7 and Linux.

```
import colorama
colorama.init( strip=False )

print( colorama.Fore.RED + "Hello World!" + colorama.Fore.RESET )
```

The text can be printed witn colors in terminals. However, colors are removed after piping like "python script.py | cat".
I guess that Python remove colors based on output tty. How can I implement behavior like `grep --color=always` and `ls --color=always`.

Comment: What do you mean by “colors are removed after redirect”?

Comment: I think he means using this script in bash with redirect, e.g. `python3 script.py | less`?

Comment: Thank you for commenting and I am sorry that I did not clarify my situations. As Andrej mentioned, I would like to keep colors in "python script.py | cat", "python script.py | less -R" and so on

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly explained in the [readme](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) for the library.

> `init()` accepts some `**kwargs` to override default behaviour.
>
> …
>
> `init(strip=None)`:
>
> > Pass `True` or `False` to override whether ansi codes should be stripped from the output. The default behaviour is to strip if on Windows or if output is redirected (not a tty).
>
> `init(convert=None)`:
>
> > Pass `True` or `False` to override whether to convert ANSI codes in the output into win32 calls. The default behaviour is to convert if on Windows and output is to a tty (terminal).

Assuming you're not on Windows, then, the answer is to pass `strip=False` instead of the default `strip=None` to `init`. This is just like passing `--color=always` instead of the default to `grep` or `ls`.

---

Of course your code isn't calling `init` in the first place. You should be, but you get away with it because you're presumably not on Windows:

> Applications should initialise Colorama using:
>
> `from colorama import init`
> `init()`
>
> On Windows, calling `init()` will filter ANSI escape sequences out of any text sent to stdout or stderr, and replace them with equivalent Win32 calls.
>
> On other platforms, calling `init()` has no effect (unless you request other optional functionality; see “Init Keyword Args”, below). By design, this permits applications to call `init()` unconditionally on all platforms, after which ANSI output should just work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and I am sorry that I did not mention my environment. I am running the code in Python 2.7 and Linux. Your advice can work in Python 3. However, init() did not work well in Python 2.7. Since I am using same version of colorama, I guess that Python 2.7 do something.